# Microsoft Edge has stopped opening EPUB files

Tags: microsoft-edge, epub

Yesterday, MS Edge was working beautifully, opening all EPUB files. Today, Edge has stopped opening EPUB files at all.

Are all my annotations lost? Is there any way to get it to open EPUB files again?

My version -

> **Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0**
>
> *Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362*
>    (2019 Microsoft) .

Comment: Did you mean the new Edge Chromium thing or the Edge browser that comes with Windows 10 pre-installed?

Comment: 1. Rather ask about the specific problem, and add some more detail (which version of Edge do you have or did you have?), 2. One question at a time please, and 3. Software recommendation questions are off topic here.

Comment: Has your EPUB opening program changed?

Comment: @Biswapriyo its an Edge browser preinstalled with Win 10 *thing*. My epub opening program has been MS Edge only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple internet search for "edge epub" will tell you what’s going on: ePub support was removed from Edge.

[This is the official Microsoft source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517840/microsoft-edge-download-an-epub-app-to-keep-reading) which unfortunately does not state a date:

> Microsoft Edge will no longer support e-books that use the .epub file extension. Visit the Microsoft Store to see our recommended .ePub apps. You can expect to see more added over time as we partner with companies like the DAISY Consortium to add additional, accessible apps.
>
> Microsoft has collaborated with our partners and the DAISY Consortium to shortlist a few accessible ePub applications within the Microsoft Store. These apps are expected to be available in the Microsoft Store after September 2019. You can review the current set of recommended apps in [the Microsoft Store collection](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/collections/thereadingroom).

[This is the patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4522355/windows-10-update-kb4522355) that removes the ePub support. Maybe uninstalling it will allow you to access your data again to export it. The export format is a somewhat human-readable JSON file.

Comment: My question was **How can I *revert* it ?**

Comment: Uninstall the update? Maybe the data is still there, though I doubt it, sorry.

Comment: I don't know how to uninstall updates for Edge only . How do i do that ?My PC is set to auto-update while shutting down/on , etc..

Comment: This is a Windows update. You have to uninstall the entire update. The update will eventually be installed again. However, you may be able to export your data.

Comment: Can I get a setup for a previous version of Edge from any other websites ?

Comment: No, you cannot. You also will not be able to use Edge for eBooks in the future.

Comment: I**t is not possible to "uninstall" KB4522355 in order to restore ePub functionality**, because KB4524570 (and all future patches) will also remove the ePub support.  **It also is not possible to restore a previous version of Edge.**

Comment: Can i stop edge from updating further if i still have a older version of edge on a different PC( which runs EPUB thankfully) and still manage to update rest of my PC ? I guess I am asking if it's possible to update selectively

Comment: Again, no. You could only stop all updates, which is obviously a bad idea. I understand that you’re frustrated. But you have to face the facts: You _will not_ be using Edge for eBooks in the future.